# How to force Chrome to refresh javascript - none of the existing solutions work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've tried everything. I've tried ctrl-shift-R. I've tried ctrl-F5. I've checked the Disable Cache box in the developer tools. I've completely cleared my browser cache. But I cannot for the life of me get Chrome (Version 24.0.1312.57 m for Windows 7 - the most up-to-date version) to reload a specific piece of inline javascript (meaning it's in my html page, not in a separate js file.)

Is there any other way I'm missing to get this done, or do I need to completely uninstall Chrome and reload? Please don't tell me to use Firefox instead; the code works in javascript but doesn't in Chrome, and I need to be able to test it there.

Comment: Is HTML5 Appcache being used?

Comment: No, we're not using Appcache.

Comment: Check for LocalStorage, etc in the Devtools.

Comment: I have. There's nothing there.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: No. This is on a secure dev box.

Comment: And yes, before you ask, I'm sure the code has made it to the dev box correctly. It does display the correct code on a different test machine in Chrome (one that had never hit that particular file before.)